# antimalware service 100% usage on building android gradle

Tags: android, flutter

I was building an android application using Flutter on Android Studio. I just added web-crypto and crypto packages and updated the codebase according to the project I was working on.
But when I started building the debug application only, while building android gradle only it started causing my laptop to start hanging, so I check at Task Manager and there was Antimalware Service Executable taking about 100% CPU usage. I stopped building and it reached normal level again. And on starting building again this happens again. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could try temporarily disabling the Windows Defender real-time protection whilst building: [See here](https://www.howtogeek.com/318556/what-is-antimalware-service-executable-and-why-is-it-running-on-my-pc/).

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem is related to the [webcrypto](https://pub.dev/packages/webcrypto) package. I have created an [issue](https://github.com/google/webcrypto.dart/issues/23) on their Github repo for now.